# How to use parallel correctly in this situation?

Tags: bash, scripting, xargs

I have a file with multiple URL's in it (separated by a newline) and want to execute a bash command for each line.

Here is the command:

```
xargs -n1 -I+ ./info.sh https://+/.info/ +/
```

How can I execute it with multiple threads per line?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`xargs -I+ -P6 ./info.sh https://+/.info/ +/`

Change the `6` to what you like.

> -P max-procs, --max-procs=max-procs
>
> ```
>          Run  up  to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If
>           max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible  at
>           a  time.
> ```

Also,
`-I`  implies `-L1`, which in this case has the same effect as `-n1`, so you don't need that here.